# EmberJS - user signin - what's the best way to approach?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a layout for user to signin, with the usual "user firstname", "lastname", "email" and a few more fields.
I'm using "component" to show this content to the user.
I also need to validate this data locally.

Now I need to tie the UI to the data.
I have two options:
1. Use model
2. Use member variables in component

And when everything is okay, when user clicks on the "register" button,
I need to send this data to the back-end.

What do you suggest is the best way to do this?

Comment: Just follow the [Tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/tutorial/ember-cli/) to learn the basic concepts of Ember. Come back if you got a specific question!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably take a look at the [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) project:

> Ember Simple Auth is a lightweight library for implementing authentication/ authorization with Ember.js applications. It has minimal requirements with respect to application structure, routes etc. With its pluggable strategies it can support all kinds of authentication and authorization mechanisms.